# getting events from database to calendar page

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

Database:
[image: Database]
Calendar 1:
[image: Calendar 1]
Calendar 2:
[image: Calendar 2]
Calendar 3:
[image: Calendar 3]

I'm trying to getting both events from the database onto Monday 4th and I'm wondering why I am only getting one event for April and May.

```
$sql = "SELECT title, contact, contact_email, DAYOFMONTH(start_date) 
        FROM $caltbl WHERE start_date LIKE '$year-$month%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$record = mysql_fetch_array($result);

while ($day_num <= $days_in_month) {
echo "<td width=\"42\" valign=\"top\">
      &nbsp;<a href='index.php?day=$day_num-$title-$year'>
      $day_num</a><p/>";

if ($day_num == $record['DAYOFMONTH(start_date)']){     
    echo "&nbsp;<a href=\"#\">".$record['title']. "</a><br/>";      
} else{
    echo "<br />&nbsp;" . "<br/>&nbsp;";
}
echo "</td>";
$day_num++;
$day_count++;
```

EDIT:

```
while ($day_num <= $days_in_month) {
echo "<td width=\"42\" valign=\"top\">&nbsp;<a href='index.php?day=$day_num-$title-$year'>$day_num</a><p/>";

if ($day_num == $record['DAYOFMONTH(start_date)']){

    while ($event = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = $event;
    }
    print_r($array);
    echo "&nbsp;<a href=\"#\">".$event['title']. "</a><br/>";

} else{
    echo "<br />&nbsp;" . "<br/>&nbsp;";
}
echo "</td>";
$day_num++;
$day_count++;

// Make sure we start a new row each week
if ($day_count > 7) {
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    $day_count = 1;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using fullcalender or any other calendar plugins? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve from the code you provide and screen.

Comment: No I'm not using any plugins. What I want to know is why I'm only getting one record for the current month when the database shows 4: two for 4/4 and one each for 4/8 and 4/17.

Comment: It is because you are creating the table cell in your database loop. So when you fetch the next row, that day (cell) is already closed, so it will jump to the next month that the day is available. It would be easier if you selected your database data and saved it to an array 1st, based on the day. And then build your calendar and pull all the day's events from the saved array.

Comment: @MawiaHL GROUP BY title didn't actually do anything.

Comment: Did you try Sean's suggestion? It's worth a try.

Comment: @MawiaHL yea it prints the print_r but when I echo the event title it does nothing, but it still doesn't print totally right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a blank array:

```
$arr = array();        
 while ($event = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr[] = $event;//store all the data in the $arr array
    }
```

Run a foreach loop to to print the event detail:

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    if($v['DATEOFMONTH(start_date)']==$day_num){
      echo '<a href="#">'.$v['title'].'</a><br/>';
    }else{
        echo "<br />&nbsp;" . "<br/>&nbsp;";
    }
  }
```

Hope this may help.  [demo](https://coderpad.io/A9X6J7MH)

Comment: Thank You that worked,  but how do I make sure all events for the day get outputed?